# Oracle compare two date

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I have oracle query I want to compare two date it work fin but when I put it inside oracle function and pass a date as parameter I get this error:

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
ORA-06512: at line 8
Process exited.
```

and this my function:

```
Create or Replace 
FUNCTION GET_MAX_VALUE 
(
  PLAN_DATE IN DATE  
, LOC IN NUMBER  
, RES IN NUMBER  
, TIS IN NUMBER  
) RETURN NUMBER AS 
units number;
return_val number;
BEGIN
  select ts.booked_units into units from tsm_transaction_tbl ts
  where ts.location_id=loc and ts.resource_id=res and ts.ts_id=tis and ts.trans_date=to_date(plan_date,'mm/dd/yyyy');

  RETURN units;
END GET_MAX_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `to_date` function that surrounds your `plan_date` variable.

You are already passing `plan_date` as `DATE` type variable. There is no need to convert it to date using `to_date` function.

Speaking about `to_date` function, it is used to convert a string (varchar2 type) to `date` type according to the format that we want. You can read more about `to_date` function on Oracle's site [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm).

Your code can be as following:

```
Create or Replace 
FUNCTION GET_MAX_VALUE 
(
  PLAN_DATE IN DATE  
, LOC IN NUMBER  
, RES IN NUMBER  
, TIS IN NUMBER  
) RETURN NUMBER AS 
units number;
return_val number;
BEGIN
  select ts.booked_units into units from tsm_transaction_tbl ts
  where ts.location_id=loc
  and ts.resource_id=res
  and ts.ts_id=tis
  and ts.trans_date = plan_date;

  RETURN units;
END GET_MAX_VALUE;
```